# Convert duration from 0:00 or 00:00 to 00:00:00

Tags: c#, time, format, duration

I'm doing up an application that converts the STRING duration of a media file in C#.
How do I make it so that the output are as follows:

a. 1:34 (1min 34 sec) to
00:01:34

b. 0:05 (5 seconds) to
00:00:05

c. 1:10:05 to 01:10:05

Result will be displayed in a label named lblDuration.

I am using VS2008 C#.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Regex doesn't seem to help, as the formats can be 1:34 or 01:34

Comment: Is the input a string and the output a string?  Seems like it, just want to be sure.

Comment: Try `String.Format({0:hh:mm:ss}, strYourTime);`.

Comment: Have you checked the TimeSpan.Parse and TimeSpan.ParseExact Methods?

Comment: @Camus - your code still gave me 1:34, which i don't want.

Comment: What i really want is 11:34 to become 00:11:34 and 1:34 to become 00:01:34 :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would parse it as a `TimeSpan`, and then reformat it using

```
string text = timeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss");
```

This is assuming you're using .NET 4 with its support for [custom `TimeSpan` formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx). Before .NET 4 you'd have to write it yourself - not too hard, but harder than the above.

Parsing the timespan to start with is a different matter - you could use `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` passing in multiple formats, for example.

The benefit of parsing and then reformatting is that you'll validate that you've got sensible date - e.g. not "99:99".

Comment: i would love to use timespan, but how do i parse something like 1:34 ?

Comment: @midend: Using TimeSpan.TryParseExact, passing it "m:ss" as the format string. You can give `TryParseExact` multiple formats to try in turn.

Comment: =.= that seems like quite an amount of work...I'll try it out though

Comment: @midend unfortunately it usually does involve work if you want to do something that is correct.

Comment: For some reason, the "hh:mm:ss" threw a format exception - had to use `timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");`

Comment: @AmbroseLeung: Whoops, yes - I meant to quote the colons in my answer. (I'd done it locally, so it's doubly embarrassing. I prefer to quote than escape though.)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with a colon (':'), convert each element to a number and print each number using %02d, putting a ':' between 1st and 2nd and 2nd and 3rd

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing it to a `DateTime` object then formatting it that way e.g.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1:32", 'H:mm', CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Just to clarify - The above solution is a work-around for .NET versions prior to 4 in which you don't have access to custom TimeSpan formats. If you are using .NET 4 then I would definitely recommend using the `TimeSpan` as @Jon has suggested

Comment: Parsing it as a `DateTime` feels like a bad idea to me, when it's *note* a `DateTime` - it's fundamentally a `TimeSpan`. This may be a workaround if the OP isn't using .NET 4 though.

Comment: @Jon - Defo agree and I was going to suggest the Timespan also, however, you beat me to it. Therefore, tried to think outside the box for a solution for versions prior to 4 :)

Comment: Makes sense. Probably worth editing your answer to explain that reasoning :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void convertString()

    {

        string str;

        str = "your time";

        int length = str.Length;

        if (length == 4)

        {

            str = "00" + ":" +"0"+ str;

       }

        if (length == 5)

       {
            str = "00" + ":" + str;

        }
```

}

```
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Program p = new Program();

        p.convertString();

    }
```

Comment: there might be a problem, since the returned string CAN also be 1:4.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static string GetLable(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return "00:00:00";
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var arr = text.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (arr.Length == 2)
            builder.Append("00:");
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var t in arr)
        {
            builder.Append(t.Length == 1 ? "0" + t : t);
            if (arr.Length - 1 != i++)
                builder.Append(":");
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the nicest thing to do here is use `TimeSpan.TryParse`, BUT we have to be careful - if that method sees an input string with only one `:`, it will parse it as `hours:minutes`!

(`TryParseExact` gets fiddly because no single format accepts both leading zeroes and the absence of leading zeroes).

So:

```
var input = "5:06";

TimeSpan ts;

var parseSuccessful = TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out ts);

if  (parseSuccessful)
{
    if (input.Count(c => c == ':') == 1)
    {
        // TryParse parsed this as hh:mm but we want it to mean mm:ss
        // so scale appropriately
        ts = new TimeSpan(ts.Ticks / 60);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
}
```